# Preemption in netty writeAndFlush

Tags: netty

I'm wondering whether it is possible to preempt the prior writeAndFlush in netty. i.e., how can I enable some priority in netty messages? If it is unlikely to enforce this priority in writeAndFlush, is it possible to handle it with eventloop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is written in the order you submit it, so there is no priority handling here. Usually you would build something like this in your protocol encoder / decoder. Just like HTTP/2 has the concept of priority.

Comment: Thank you very much! So (i) There is no case for the current flushed data to preempt the prior one, and the data will always be sent in this FIFO order w/o interrupt? (ii) When we flush the write, I am wondering whether it is the trace of this I/O action: OutBoundBuffer -> TCP buffer, and no other intermediate buffer anymore? Meanwhile, the size of this outbound buffer is determined by the WATER_MARK (32K~64K)? Thanks!